# Push to github from behind a proxy

Tags: git, proxy

On my college network, There is no direct access to the Internet. We have to go through a Proxy Server. I have already setup the proxy server on Windows from the control panel. I have also set it up in Firefox(Which happens to be the browser the college prefers).

I can access all the web pages and in general I have internet access. But when I try to push to github from either the GUI application or the Shell, There is always a fatal error that says `fatal: unable to access https://github.com/username/repo.git`.

I can access all the webpages from all the installed browsers, suggesting that the settings for the proxy servers are perfect.

I have tried to set the http and https proxy to the IP address given to us from the college. But it does not seem to work. I used the `set` command in the git shell.

Comment: Excuse this off-topic comment, but what what were you thinking [suggesting this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2688563)? Things like "thanks", "please help" etc are not supposed to be edited _in_ but _removed_, they add nothing to the question but length- politeness is implicitly assumed

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to push using the [Corkscrew](http://www.mtu.net/~engstrom/ssh-proxy.php) tool. Otherwise, you may have to take a laptop to somewhere with real internet and push from there. I actually have to do that at my workplace where I am a computer programmer. Ridiculous but true.

Comment: There must be a way?? I mean you are telling me that I can't push to any server, not GitHub, Dropbox, Google Drive from a local folder on the computer. That seems to be ridiculous alright..!

Answer (score 0):

As they say there is always a way!

Simply install TortoiseGit and then in the context menu you can go to TortoiseGit -> Settings -> Network -> Enable Proxy and add the proxy settings. once you do that everything works perfectly fine!!

@Joe Beuckman -- You don't have to now!

**P.S.** And there is a lot more to tortoiseGit then just Proxy Settings!